Limit to zero of Expected value of a function of random variable
I am trying to solve a problem but I don't know how to get out.
Let's say we have a composition of functions of random variable $f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))$ (differentiable and invertible) and $X$ has $p(x)$ as pdf. I would like to find a closed form of:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\nabla_{\theta,\phi}f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))^2] = μ\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\nabla_{\theta,\phi}f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))]
$$
where $\mu$ = $\mathbb{E}[X]$.
After some computations is possible to arrive to:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\nabla_{\theta,\phi}f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X)) ( f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X)) - \mu)] = 0
$$
I empirically found that this happens when $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))] = \mu$ but I am not able to prove it formally.
One route that I was going to try is: since the gradient tends to zero during the convergence (considering for example the usage of stochastic gradient descent) it's (maybe) possible to rewrite it in this way:
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow{} 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))h]}{\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[h]}
$$
where $h = \nabla_{\theta,\phi}f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))$. Now, if I were able to demostrate that this limit tends to $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f_{\theta}(g_{\phi}(X))]$ it's done. But I am struggling to solve this limit too.
Thank you so much, every kind of help is appreciated.
